# How to use rowDoubleClick in Angular if same ag-grid is used accross multiple components?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an `ag-grid` which is used in 4 different `Angular` Components. I want to enable `rowDoubleClicked` only for one component. But when I give it in the grid it is getting enabled for all the component.

How do I make it enable only one specific method that is being emitted for that particular component?

I read that we can use `this.gridOptions.onRowDoubleClicked` in the component.ts file, but not sure how do I use it exactly for a particular method.

template :-

```
<ag-grid-angular
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [rowData]="rowData"
      [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
      (rowDoubleClicked) = "onRowDoubleClick()"
      gridOptions="{{ gridOptions }}"
    >
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

component.ts :-

```
onRowDoubleClick(){
     console.log("Double Click works for a particular component");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the gridOptions in your component and pass it to the template.
Something like this,

Inside template:

```
[gridOptions]="gridOptions"
```

In component:

```
export class YourComp {
   gridOptions: GridOptions; //Declare gridoptions
   constructor(){
        this.gridOptions = {
        onRowDoubleClick: yourMethod()
      }
  }
}
```